# SDL2 долго выполняется

Tags: c++, sdl2

В программе выполняются операции над полем, то есть над элементами двумерного массива. Сам просчет идет быстро, но способ вывода этих значений попиксельно на экран занимает прилично времени. Можно ли оптимизировать код? Как пример, прилагаю общий вид алгоритма вывода. В этом примере попиксельное обновление фона очень долго выполняется.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <SDL.h>
using namespace std;

bool cont = true;

const int window_width = 700;
const int window_height = 700;

SDL_Window* window;
SDL_Renderer* r;
//SDL_Texture* t = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(r, 0);
void init(const char* title, int x, int y, int w, int h, int flags) {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) >= 0) {
        window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, x, y, w, h, flags);
        if (window != 0)
        {
            r = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
        }
    }
}

void handleEvents()
{
    SDL_Event event;
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            cont = false;
        }
    }
}

void exit()
{
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(r);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
}

void render() {
    int red = (rand() % 2) * 255;
    int green = (rand() % 2) * 255;
    int blue = (rand() % 2) * 255;

    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < window_height; i1++)
    {
        int y = i1;

        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < window_width; i2++)
        {
            int x = i2;

            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(r, red, green, blue, 255);
            SDL_RenderDrawPoint(r, i2, i1);
        }
    }

    SDL_RenderPresent(r);
}

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    init("Title", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, window_width, window_height, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    while (cont)
    {
        render();
        handleEvents();
    }

    exit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: рисуйте на bitmap или массиве, а потом отрисовывайте одним подходом. Попиксельное рисования редко бывает быстрым

Comment: Рисуйте используя видеокарту. `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(r, red, green, blue, 255); SDL_RenderClear(r);`, а то как в анекдоте - взял билет и не поехал.

Comment: А ещё рекомендуют использовать функцию SDL_LockSurface

Comment: KoVadim, каким образом можно рисовать в массиве в sdl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <SDL.h>
using namespace std;

bool cont = true;

const int window_width = 700;
const int window_height = 700;

SDL_Window* window;
SDL_Surface* s;
void init(const char* title, int x, int y, int w, int h, int flags) {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) >= 0) {
        window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, x, y, w, h, flags);
        if (window != 0)
        {
            s = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
        }
    }
}

void handleEvents()
{
    SDL_Event event;
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            cont = false;
        }
    }
}

void exit()
{
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_FreeSurface(s);
    SDL_Quit();
}

void render() {
    /*int red = (rand() % 2) * 255;
    int green = (rand() % 2) * 255;
    int blue = (rand() % 2) * 255;*/
    int red = 255;
    int green = 0;
    int blue = 0;

    int rgb = red;
    rgb = (rgb << 8) + green;
    rgb = (rgb << 8) + blue;

    Uint32* pixels = (Uint32*)s->pixels;

    SDL_LockSurface(s);
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < window_height; i1++)
    {
        int y = i1;

        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < window_width; i2++)
        {
            int x = i2;

            pixels[(y * s->w) + x] = rgb;
        }
    }
    SDL_UnlockSurface(s);

    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
}

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    init("Title", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, window_width, window_height, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    while (cont)
    {
        render();
        handleEvents();
    }

    exit();
    return 0;
}
```